# How do I compare one condition different columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 6 columns and I have 5 statuses like these:

```
column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 ,column6 
status1, status2, status3, status4, status5
```

How can I compare them like this:

`column1 ,column2 , column3 , column4 ,column5 ,column6` 
can be `in  (status1, status2, status3, status4 ,status5)`.

Comment: and what is the logical link between `column1 ,column2 , column3 , column4 ,column5 ,column6`? AND or OR?

Comment: Column names with incremented numbers have a bad smell of a non-normalized model - and your question also seems to indicate that. Maybe you should re-think your design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each column can separately take any of the named statuses and it is required that each column have one of the mentioned statuses, you could simply do:

```
column1 IN (status1, status2, status3, status4, status5) AND 
column2 IN (status1, status2, status3, status4, status5) AND 
column3 IN (status1, status2, status3, status4, status5) AND
column4 IN (status1, status2, status3, status4, status5) AND
column5 IN (status1, status2, status3, status4, status5) AND
column6 IN (status1, status2, status3, status4, status5)
```

If it is enough to have at least one column in any of the statuses, `OR` should be used instead of `AND`.